# Matlab's Logicals for Array Indexing - Python Equivalent

Tags: python, indexing, mask

In MATLAB there is a masking type of operation with logicals like this one:

```
A=randn(1,10)  % vector with 10 random values

% logical mask indexing:
A(A<0)=NaN     % setting values smaller than 0 to NaN
```

Is there an equivalent operation that simple in Python?
I didn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random
a = [random.random() - 0.5 for _ in range (10)]
a = [None if i < 0 else i for i in a]
```

You may want to consider `numpy` if you're using long arrays (and if you're doing MATLAB-like stuff) as it can be much more efficient.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(10) - 0.5
a[a<0] = np.NaN
```